# Having some problems with pointers. Converting hex to decimal int in C

Tags: c, pointers

I already have the code but it's not working since I suspect I have messed up my pointers.

The problem is supposed to convert a given decimal into hexadecimal. And we're supposed to do it manually so that's why I can't use printf to print it or use strtol or whatever.

Here is my code:

Comment: Oh thanks, I fixed that. And also edited what output I'm getting.

Comment: And what is exactly the output you're seeing?

Comment: I edited the question to include the output. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`while (&ptr != '\0')` should be `while (*ptr != '\0')` if you're trying to dereference the pointer.

Also,

```
while (*ptr != '\0') {
        ptr++; 
        base++;
}
// ptr points to the end of the string now. The condition in the next line can't be true.
while (*ptr != '\0') {
    switch (*ptr) {
        case '0': 
            replaceInt = 0;
...
```

the first loop will advance ptr so that the loop after it will never be entered.

Comment: I'm actually aware of this. Everyone else I've asked has told me this but I don't know how to fix it :(

Comment: You can set `ptr = string` when you're done with the first loop.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did and moved the decimal num at the end of the while loop and it works perfectly now. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what nmicheals said.
The last 3 lines of your function seem like they belong inside the last while loop. Otherwise you only change their values only once for the last digit.

Answer (score 0):

This loop guarantees that your parsing loop will never run.

```
  while (&ptr != '\0') { // As noted by the other poster you want *ptr instead of &ptr
        ptr++; 
        base++;
    }
```

You need to reset the pointer after this loop so that your next loop will run.

```
ptr=string;
```

Comment: Ah so that was it. Thanks everyone it works now. I also fixed my code to move modyfying the decimalNum and ptr++ and base-- to the end of the while loop and just left the return statment up there.

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs in the wrong direction.  The string "2ef" is parsed right to left. But the value of ptr is sitting at the '\0' value when fining the end the string and never runs through the while loop.  Also the ptr needs to be decremented and base increased.  I've set base to be 0 when processing the 1's digit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int convertHexToDec(char *string);

/* Runs the main program and asks for user input */
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char* programName;
    programName = argv[0];

    /* Prints an error if user's input is less than 1 argument. */
    if(argc <= 1) {
        printf("Error: Not enough arguments.\n");
    }

    if (argc >= 2) {
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i <= argc - 1; ++i) {
            printf("%s = %d\n", argv[i], convertHexToDec(argv[i]));
        }

    }
    return 0;
}

int convertHexToDec(char* string) {
    char *ptr;
    ptr = string;
    int decimalNum = 0, base = 0, replaceInt = 0;

    while (*ptr != '\0') {
        ptr++;
    }
    ptr--;

    while (*ptr != '\0') {
        switch (*ptr) {
            case '0':
                replaceInt = 0;
                break;
            case '1':
                replaceInt = 1;
                break;
            case '2':
                replaceInt = 2;
                break;
            case '3':
                replaceInt = 3;
                break;
            case '4':
                replaceInt = 4;
                break;
            case '5':
                replaceInt = 5;
                break;
            case '6':
                replaceInt = 6;
                break;
            case '7':
                replaceInt = 7;
                break;
            case '8':
                replaceInt = 8;
                break;
            case '9':
                replaceInt = 9;
                break;
            case 'a':
                replaceInt = 10;
                break;
            case 'b':
                replaceInt = 11;
                break;
            case 'c':
                replaceInt = 12;
                break;
            case 'd':
                replaceInt = 13;
                break;
            case 'e':
                replaceInt = 14;
                break;
            case 'f':
                replaceInt = 15;
                break;
            default:
                printf("Wrong input");
                exit(0);
        }
        decimalNum += pow(16, base) * replaceInt;
        ptr--;
        base++;
    }

    return decimalNum;
}
```